# Skipping an Android Test at runtime based on a condition

Tags: java, android, junit

Is there any way to skip an Android test case execution at runtime if a specific condition is not satisfied? 
(eg: the device under test doesn't have a specific feature)

I have tried using junit.Assume methods, but when the Android test runners (InstrumentationTestRunner and AndroidJUnitRunner) receive the thrown exception (org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException) the test case is marked as fail.

What I need is to have the test case with neither pass or fail in the result, just skipped.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but there is the [SdkSuppress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/filters/SdkSuppress.html) annotation that you can add to prevent a test from running on older API levels.

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/ ?

Comment: @SiKing, unfortunately, no, as it says: _"The remaining issue with Assume is that it affects the test statistics. If an Assume condition is found to be false, it treats the test as having passed even though it hasn’t run."._ So I'll still have the test case with a result (pass). However, there is an useful information on this site, it says that I'd need to provide my own test runner in order to handle the **AssumptionViolatedException** the way I want. Maybe this is the only thing I can do..  (Thanks for sharing this link)